# Sql query transferring only alternating rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the following query. I am moving 1000 rows from 1 table to another.
But, it just transfers the alternating 1000 rows, thats it.

If I remove the cte clause, I get full data. Can you let me know where am I wrong ?

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @TableCount INT = 0
set @TableCount = (select count(*) from TableSource)
print @TableCount/@BatchSize //10000/1000

while @Counter < (@TableCount/@BatchSize+1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TableDest   
    SELECT *    
    FROM TableSource MH
    inner join Table1 M
    on MH.Mid = M.Mid   
    order by HID OFFSET (@BatchSize * @Counter)ROWS FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY;


    with cte as
    (
    SELECT HID
    FROM TableSource MH
    inner join Table1 M
    on MH.Mid = M.Mid   
    order by message_history_id OFFSET (@BatchSize * @Counter)ROWS FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY
    )
    delete from TableSource where HID IN (select cte.HID from cte)

SET @Counter=@Counter+1;
END
```

Why is it just inserting alternating 1000 rows ?

```
It only transfers following rows if the total rows are 10,000:
0-1000
2001-3000
4001-5000
6001-7000
8001-9000
```

I have huge data, so I am doing this way. I DO NOT WANT TO LOCK THE WHOLE TABLE, SO I CANT SELECT OR DELETE ALL THE CONTENT AT ONCE.

Comment: @Felix It still transfers half the rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove counter from selection

```
DECLARE @BatchSize INT = 1000
DECLARE @Counter INT = 0
DECLARE @TableCount INT = 0
set @TableCount = (select count(*) from TableSource)
print @TableCount/@BatchSize //10000/1000

while @Counter < (@TableCount/@BatchSize+1)
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO TableDest   
    SELECT *    
    FROM TableSource MH
    inner join Table1 M
    on MH.Mid = M.Mid   
    order by HID OFFSET (0/* REMOVED@BatchSize  * @Counter */)ROWS FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY;


    with cte as
    (
    SELECT HID
    FROM TableSource MH
    inner join Table1 M
    on MH.Mid = M.Mid   
    order by message_history_id OFFSET (0/* REMOVED@BatchSize  * @Counter*/)ROWS FETCH NEXT @Batchsize ROWS ONLY
    )
    delete from TableSource where HID IN (select cte.HID from cte)
SET @Counter=@Counter+1;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're deleting first 1000 rows from source table after copying. Next time you're applying 1000 offset again. Move the cte clause outside the loop and delete all at once, you should be fine.

Edit: Other option would be to remove the offset from your insert & delete statements and retain the cte clause inside the loop.

Comment: I cant do that, i dont want to lock the whole table, it has huge data in the table.

Comment: If I remove the offset, I cant get 1000 rows at a time. First I want 0-1000, then 1001-2000, 2001-3000 etc. How can I get in this format without offset?

Comment: Because you're deleting the first 1000 rows after copying! No need of offset for copying the next 1000 because they'll be the first 1000, after deleting the actual first 1000!

Comment: I thought of that, but I dont want to lock the whole table, so cant do select * or something without offset and 2nd thing is I have where condition, means some rows cant match too

Comment: You won't lock. Remove the offset and put a limit 1000

Comment: Can you explain me more ? Can you write that part of query ?

Comment: Ok, understood but if i remove offset, it wont skip first 1000, first 2000. ANd i need good performance, and it makes sense to skip it right ?

Comment: `Select TOP 1000 *` and `select TOP 1000 HID` instead of just selecting, and remove your offset parts

Comment: Do you see it? You have to just operate on top 1000 all the time because you're deleting the top 1000 after copying.

Comment: But, if I do not get any data from top 1000 (based on a where clause), it will go into the infinite loop and always see that top 1000.

Comment: Your while loop will prevent it. Try  querying. You'll get it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, but when I do select top 1000 *, it will atleast scan the whole table. And i cant lock that.